# Stacking divs and using a toggle to show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stack

I'm currently taking a web development class and looking to go beyond the "scope" of the class. I managed to create a jquery slide show in a div, now id like to show case some other features in two other divs, stack them into a single div and and call them via a set of toggles. Any methods or roads that can be suggested?

By stacked I mean three divs, one on top of the other. One of these divs is a jquery slider. I'd like a toggle to show one and hide the other two. I'll try and post code after I make it home from work.

Comment: please provide your current source code.

Comment: do you have your source code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 2 divs stacked in one, or what the toggle is supposed to do/what graphical effect you were envisioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "stack", but [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) might be a simple solution to get what you're looking for.

It also has methods that you could call from other ~buttons~ to trigger to show/hide effect.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this in CSS, just changed the visibility of the divs based on a link; probably not optimal but I thought it was kinda nifty.

Answer (score 0):

You could even make the three divs into a slide show that is triggered by clicking some navigation like forward and back arrows.  Look into the [Anything Slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/).